# Enable a button on partial validation dropdown - Semantic UI (very weird work around)

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

**Goal**

Checking if 1 column of dropdowns is selected and enable the button within the semantic UI. (See working example below). Final version of my project will have 6 "columns"/"screens" like that.

**Question**

Can't it be done easier/cleaner? As you can see in the fiddle, it runs the code for every column.

**How did i got it working**

Don't ask me haha... After a 100 attempts with multiple if and else work arounds I ended up with assigning an ID to the current class with "$(this)". After that it looks if the ID is not empty for all the ellements with the same class. If none of the element ID's is empty it enables the button. I used the code below to make it work. Thanks to: [Enable/Disable Button when multiple dropdown value is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930775/enable-disable-button-when-multiple-dropdown-value-is-selected)

**Code i found on stackoverflow**

```
$(function () {
        $('.picker').on('change', function () {     
            var SelectList = $('.picker');
            //Here i'll find how many dropdown are present
            for (var i = 0; i < SelectList.length ; i++) {
                //Here i need to check each dropdown value whether it selected or not
                if (SelectList[i].value != "") {
                    //If all dropdown is selected then Enable button
                    $("#Testing").attr("disabled", false);
                }
                else {
                    //Disable button if any dropdown is not selected
                    $("#Testing").attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
```

**Code above but editted to my wishes**

```
$(function () {
        $('#myform2').on('change', function () {     
            var SelectList = $('.ui.dropdown.selection.thisistwo');
                for (var i = 0; i < SelectList.length ; i++) {
                if (SelectList[i].id != "") {
                    $(".ui.right.labeled.icon.button.n2").attr( "disabled", false);
                }
                else {
                     $(".ui.right.labeled.icon.button.n2").attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
```

As you can see I use "SelectList[i].id" in order to check if the id is emtpy with: != ""

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/StaphWar/kLy7ow61/62/

**Update -> Fixed by NERBIZ <3**

Just figured out that this isn't working either. If you select something from the dropdowns at the bottom, it will enable the button without the dropdowns above being selected. And I've just implemented it in my project. -.-

**New goal**
Optional fields. So if someone selects "no" it would hide 2 dropdowns and the validation and the next button is enabled. Not to hard right? Most work arounds that I tried didn't. When switching between the options "yes" and "no" the button sooner or later ended up staying disabled/enabled. Or the final validation didn't work when "yes" was selected.

Tried a bunch of things untill I made a mistake that actually worked.

```
(($(SelectList[i]).dropdown('get value') == "") && (THISISNOTHING == 'yes' ))
```

Where you see "THISISNOTHING" I made a typo that magicly made it work. Untill I looked in the console. Since the "THISISNOTHING" is not defined. So far the code of project had 0 errors. This kinda triggers my OCD haha.

**New goal: JSFiddle  Working but with console errors**
https://jsfiddle.net/StaphWar/kLy7ow61/170/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kLy7ow61/88/

'disable' starts as false, and if any dropdown in the column doesn't have a value, it becomes true.

```
$(function () {
  $('#myform').on('change', function () {
    var SelectList = $('.ui.dropdown.selection.thisisone');
    var disable = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < SelectList.length ; i++) {
      if ($(SelectList[i]).dropdown('get value') == "") {
        disable = true;
      }
    }

    $(".ui.right.labeled.icon.button.n1").attr( "disabled", disable);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: You made my day! The bug is solved and this is pretty easy to implement. Thank you very much!